# Storing sensitive information in a class protected variable considered safe?

Tags: php, database, class

**Please note:**  I have limited this script to show basic structure.  It is not functional.

```
class AuthController
{
   protected $dump = NULL;

   private function recall()
   {
      $dump = $this->query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE access="id" ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1');
      $this->dump = mysql_fetch_array($dump);
   }
}

$user = new AuthController($id);
```

Keep in mind the dump would contain an array of.
1.) id (auto assortment).
2.) unique name.
3.) salt - (random salt hashed with password).
4.) password (hashed).

Now, to my questions and purpose.  I must dump the users data into a variable to prepare the password for a test to see if the password matches the hashed one stored with the user in the database.

An alternative to this would be to use two queries. The *first* which would retrive the salt associated with the user in the db - (use salt to **prepare password** to match with hash). And the *second* query would pass the **prepared password** along with the users id or unique name to see if a match occurs.  I think this is unnecessary use of a database resource; when this information can be stored for later use.

One must ask, is this a risk from a security stand point?

Answer (score 1):

Everything you do on the server side without interaction with the user can be considered safe. It would not do to start worrying about the information the server has in memory because we would go crazy. If someone knows what's in your servers memory, he's gained full access to your system anyways (or his name is John Skeet).

Make sure:

- Your error reporting is well configured, meaning no displaying of errors on any live or staging environment
- Your interaction with the user is always safe (validation, escaping, quoting, etc.)
- You don't store plain text information about the user in cookies

Comment: Haha, cookies and plain text, rofl.  Thank God I am past that at my expertise.

Comment: Mark I am really happy with your reply.  I am being overly paranoid.